# Is it possible to mirror port to capture packets between VM host and VM?

Tags: vmware-workstation, port-mirroring

I have 2 physical machines, A and B.  A runs VMWare Workstation with a virtual machine C.  C is using Bridged network interface.

A and B are both connected via ethernet to a switch.  B has two NIC's.  If I used port mirroring on A's connection to the switch, and then put that into B, would I be able to capture traffic between A and C?  Does that traffic go to the switch, or does it get short circuited somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @sysadmin1138.  What about VM to VM traffic on the same host?  I simplified the example a little bit.  Actually A has 2 VM's, C and D.  I want to know if I can capture packets from C to D with B.  The VM set up is a test environment.  In deployment, C and D are actually physical machines and there is no A.

Comment: I'm not sure about workstation, actually. I suspect that functionality is not present because of how the software bridge works, but it could be wrong.

Comment: I think I'm kinda getting on the right track and can do research myself.  Thanks. [link](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/170529), [link](http://www.techexams.net/forums/virtualization/31818-vmware-promiscuous-mode.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware Workstation network traffic does indeed short-circuit inside of the host machine. Traffic from VMs on that machine to the host itself will never hit that Ethernet switch. It's a kind of virtual switch inside the Host, so traffic that can be handled locally will be handled locally; no need to forward it to the switch in the closet.

In order to capture that traffic, the capture has to be performed on the host itself. I do this frequently when checking on things like startup-traffic for a VM.